# Jquery duplicate dynamic checkboxes not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I am creating dynamic forms inside each game fixture so they can invite players.
When creating the team sheet I take the name and create a list.

```
/* Get team players information */
                    if (data.team_members){
                        $.each(data.members,function(index,item){
                            if (data.r_id <= 2){
                                members += '<tr class="refresh"><td style="padding: 0.20em;">'+
                                '<a href="#">'+item.forename+'  '+item.surname+'</a>'+
                                '</td><td style="padding: 0.20em;">'+item.role;
                            }else{
                                members += '<tr class="refresh">'+
                                    '<td style="padding: 0.20em;">'+item.forename+' '+item.surname+'</td>'+
                                    '<td style="padding: 0.20em;">'+item.role;
                            }
                            if (item.r_id == 3){
                                invite += '<li>'+item.forename+' '+item.surname+
                                    '<input type="checkbox" id="check'+i+'" name="invites[]" value="'+item.p_id+'" checked/>'+
                                    '<label style="float:right;" for="check'+i+'">&nbsp;</label></li>'; 
                            i++;
                            }
                            members += '</td></tr>';

                        });
                        $("#team_list > tbody:last-child").append(members);
                    }
```

The trouble is the checkboxes, I create a **var invite** and all the names of the players go into the variable.
Later in the code I add the dynamic form

```
f +='</center></td></tr><tr><td class="invite_form-'+i+'" style="display:none;">'+
                                    '<form id="iForm'+i+'" name="addIForm'+i+'"><ul class="alt">'+invite+'</ul>'+
                                    '<a href="#" id="submitInvite'+i+'" class="button submitInvite fit small">Submit</a>'+
                                    '</form></td></tr>';
                                i++;
                            }
```

The page loads and I can open the forms. The first form works and i can click the checkboxes. When I open the second form, the checkboxes click for the first form.

I am assuming its because of the checkbox id's. Has anybody come across this issue before.

Comment: Why are you declaring and increment the variable inside of the forEach loop when you can just use the index param the same way you use item inside of the callback? Try id="check' + index + ' " ' instead of what you're using now. Or, you could use the item.p_id to concatenate the id of the input as well.

Comment: It's probably beacause the checkboxes' name attribute are the same. Try creating unique names for each set of checkboxes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed it to a Json array

```
if (item.r_id == 3){
                                tmp ={  'fore': item.forename,
                                        'sur': item.surname,
                                        'p_id': item.p_id
                                     }
                                jsonObj.push(tmp);
                            }
```

And then I looped the json and incremented the id for every checkbox created, So it didn't matter how many I created

```
f +='</center></td></tr><tr><td class="invite_form-'+i+'" style="display:none;">'+
                                    '<form id="iForm-'+i+'" name="addIForm-'+i+'"><ul class="alt">';
                                $.each(jsonObj, function(index, item) {
                                    f += '<li>'+item.fore+'<input type="checkbox" id="check-'+m+'" name="invites[]" value="" checked/>'+
                                    '<label style="float:right;" for="check-'+m+'">&nbsp;</label></li>';
                                    m++;
                                });
                                f += '</ul>'+
                                    '<a href="#" id="submitInvite-'+i+'" class="button submitInvite fit small">Submit</a>'+
                                    '</form></td></tr>';
                                i++;
                            }
```

Thats how I got around it this time